# How to highlight missing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I have an obj-c iOS app that use CorePlot to print a chart of computed angles. x-axis for angle domain and y-axis for time. The chart change during time scrolling from top to bottom in order to show the degree. The y-axis is centred on mean value of these angle array. The data source i s NSMutableArray that a contains degrees.

An external module, every second, analyse raw data in order to generate a new computed angle to show in chart. The chart is updated very second and the y-axis scroll down showing the flow of time (something like CorePlot demo project with timer for continuous scrolling data but vertical not horizontal).

Sometimes this operation cannot generate (the angle is the same as the last one computed) a new angle but I still have to update the chart to show the flow of time. The question are:

1) Can I change color for these point in orde to highlight missing data for this range of time?

2) Can I highlight this area to show where the data is not present? Something like this (but vertical style)
https://keystrokecountdown.com/articles/corePlot/index.html

This is my current implementation:

1) Configuring plot area (some graphics setup)

```
- (void)initPlot  {
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
}
```

2) Data source. Select data from data source (array) to show in chart. x=array value, y=array index

```
#pragma mark - Core Plot Data Source

- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {

    if ([((NSString *)plot.identifier) isEqualToString:@"MY_ID"]) {
        return [degreesArray count];
    }
}

- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    NSNumber *num;

    if ([((NSString *)plot.identifier) isEqualToString:@"MY_ID"]) {
        if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {
        num = [degreesArray objectAtIndex:index];
    } else {
        num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)index + currentIndex - (int)degreesArray.count];
    }

}

return num;
```

}

3) Updating chart with new angle

```
- (void)newSetData:(int)newData {

    // Check the correct plot
    CPTGraph *leftGraph = self.leftPlot.hostedGraph;
    CPTPlot *leftPlot = [leftGraph plotWithIdentifier:@"MY_ID"];

    if (leftPlot) {

        if (degreesArray.count > kDataOnGraph) {
            NSRange range;
            range.location = 0;
            range.length = degreesArray.count-kDataOnGraph;
            [degreesArray removeObjectsInRange:range];
            [leftPlot deleteDataInIndexRange:range];
        }

        // Updating y axis range
        [self updateSetYAxis];

        currentIndex++;

        newAngle = ...;

        // Saving new SET data
        [degreesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)newAngle]];
        lastAngle_ = [NSNumber numberWithInt:newAngle];

        // Adding new SET data to chart
        [leftPlot insertDataAtIndex:degreesArray.count - 1 numberOfRecords:1];

        // Updating axis
        [self updateSetXAxis];
        [self updateSetLabels];

     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your `<CPTScatterPlotDataSource>`, implement the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` method to provide symbols for each data point. Use one for points with new data and another for points without. You will get better drawing performance if you reuse the symbol object for points with the same appearance rather that creating a new symbol for every plot point.
2. Use background limit bands on the y-axis to highlight the missing data ranges.